# Why do my emacs comint buffers sometimes seem to share the same history?

Tags: emacs

I often have several comint buffers open at once, for example I'll have a SQLi buffer open to a database and a set of shell buffers open in various places. Sometimes, for no reason I can detect, all of these buffers start to share a common buffer command history, such that M-p will pull up my last SQL command in a shell-mode buffer, and so on.

How can I fix this? What on earth is causing it?

Comment: The history is stored in comint-input-ring and this is a buffer local variable. I can't reproduce your problem. Could you provide a test case that reproduce the problem each time ?

Comment: Regrettably, no; it happens with no discernible pattern.

Comment: What is the value of your comint-input-ring-file-name variable ? Comint can store history into a file where each input is separated by \n . If your commands has \n in it, that could be a problem.

Comment: Which version of emacs are you running, and on which operating system?

Comment: Emacs 23.1.1, Mac OSX (the one from http://emacsformacosx.com/)

Comment: What does C-c C-l return? Are all of the command histories intermingled in one buffer, or are you able to discern a specific buffer that ends up replacing all of the rest?

Comment: you might also want to check your ~/.history ~/.bash_history and ~/.sh_history files when this issue happens, to see whether what you see in your shells matches what's in one of the history files.

Comment: You might actually have your configuration using one as the file to store all of your input ring data - if you search for the "input-ring" string through your configuration, you can double check that all the values are reasonable

Comment: Next time it happens I'll check those.

Comment: So, for what it's worth, C-c C-l shows all of the history items intermingled. I have no special configuration for any *input-ring* values in my .emacs.d.

Comment: emacs on mac is a bit messed up because of the graphics situation.  Are you running it in text mode only, or using X?

I ask only because I gave up quickly on emacs and went to Aquamacs, which is the only Mac-native written emacs.  I would at least try it

Comment: The build I'm using is the mac-native build; there've been mac-native builds of Emacs for years, this is the latest in a long line of 'em. X11 doesn't enter into the equation (In fact the only app I have that uses it is wireshark :/ ).  Aquamacs changes too much about the way Emacs interacts as Emacs to be useable to me. I've tried it and hated it (twice!)

Comment: Not sure that SQL tag is appropriate since a SQL guru couldn't contribute to the answer.

Comment: Chris, can you summarize in your question what emacs version you are using and on what system?  when the error appears again, you could also write down the directory in which you started up each of the comint buffers.  I tried on various debian and ubuntu systems, with emacs 23 and 22 and I could not reproduce what you say.

Answer (score 1):

Have you exited from any of the shells or SQL sessions? Long time since I used emacs but I seem to remember when a shell terminated the commands would be part of a 'global-command-history-list'.

note - A shell can quit, but the buffer will still be there in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is something else going on in your system that you are not aware of. One possibility may be something in your .emacs is mixing between buffers without your knowledge. Another possibility is that you are inadvertently moving data through your copy-and-paste system.